# What's the xpath syntax to get tag names?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse a large XML file. Say I've got the following structure:

```
<menagerie>
  <penguin>Pablo</penguin>
  <penguin>Mortimer</penguin>
  <bull>Ferdinand</bull>
  <aardvark>James Cornelius Madison Humphrey Zophar Handlebrush III</aardvark>
</menagerie>
```

I can count the non-penguins like this:

```
xml.xpath('//menagerie//*[not(penguin)]').length // 2
```

But how do I get a list of the tags, like this? (The exact format isn't important; I just want to visually scan the non-penguins.)

```
bull
aardvark
```

### Update

This gave me the list I wanted - thanks **Oded** and **TMN** and **delnan**!

```
xml.xpath('//menageries/*[not(penguin)]').each do |node|
  puts node.name()
end
```

Comment: The `xpath` call gives you the elements matched (as a collection of some sort, I assume). Why can't you grap each item's `.tagname` (or something similar) attribute?

Comment: @delnan - I'm not in bash, but in the Rails console, so piping through grep doesn't work (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Not `grep`. Collecting each item's tag name. In Ruby. Something like `tags = xml.xpath(...).collect { |tag| tag.tagname}`.

Comment: You can make this shorter with `xml.xpath(...).map(&:name)` in Ruby 1.9

Comment: Note that it is not very Ruby-like to include parentheses in a method call when there are no parameters.

Comment: @Phrogz - it's not common, but it does give you a clearer debugging message, since the interpreter now knows that you're trying to use a method and not a variable.

Comment: @NathanLong FWIW, if you have `foo.bar` then `bar` is always a method call. But you make a good point, that doing just `bar()` is less ambiguous for the interpreter in case of error than `bar`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`name()`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_name.html) or [`local-name()`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_local-name.html) XPath function.

See the examples on [zvon](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/OutputExamples/example_2_74_frame.html).

Comment: I must be doing it wrong.  `xml.xpath('//meagerie/*[not(penguin)]').name()` gets me an undefined method error; same for `.local-name`. Also tried with parens: `name()`, `local-name()`. It's `NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x122f06c48>`

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand them. Is `name()` supposed to go inside the xpath? I tried that, too, but got an invalid syntax error. It doesn't appear to be a Nokogiri method.

Comment: @Nathan Long - I think these should just work: `xml.xpath('name()')` or `xml.xpath('local-name()')`

Comment: Looks like you're getting a `NodeSet` back, you'll need to iterate it and invoke `.name()` on each element.

Comment: Seems you are using XPath 1.0. In XPath 2.0 an expression can return a sequence of strings: so distinct-values(//*/local-name()) will return the distinct element names. Sadly, XPath 1.0 can return a set of nodes, but only a single string; so you'll have to retrieve the nodes in your XPath, and get their names using host-language coding.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a bit outdated but you should do: `xml.xpath('//meagerie/*[not(penguin)]/name()')` as the expression. Note the slash, not the dot. This is how you call methods on the current node in XPath.