# Find node whose text value matches another node

Tags: xpath

How can I find nodes that contain the name of another node?

For example, if `<a>` exists and `<b>` contains the text "a" then I wish to select `<b>` but not if the name given doesn't exist.

```xml
<root>
    <a /> <!-- Do not care what is in this for now -->
    <b>a</b> <!-- Find this node only -->
    <b>c</b> <!-- This node is unwanted -->
</root>
```

I know I can compare `name()` and `text()` values effectively, the following finds nodes that reference themselves and excludes others:

```
*[name() = text()]
```

My attempt to find other references fails because `text()` in this query is in the wrong context:

```
b[../*[name() = text()]]
```

The above simply returns all `<b>` when there is at least one sibling containing it's own name, perhaps if there is `<a>a</a>`.

I need to compare a node's text with [a collection of names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8192829/471559).  I believe this should be what I am looking for but `*/name()` throws a syntax error:

```
b[text() = ../*/name()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't think this is possible in XPath 1.0**, because XPath 1.0 doesn't provide expressions/clauses for defining range variables. Also, XPath 1.0 doesn't allow a function call to be a location step.

**An XPath 2.0 solution is easy**:

```
b[. = ../*//name()]
```

Comment: That explains why PHP gives a syntax error, it doesn't yet support 2.0.  I have no choice but to step through each reference and check them explicitly.

Comment: @clockworkgeek, Yes, isn't it possible to use another XSLT processor, such as Saxon, Altova or XQSharp?

Comment: Not with the application I am developing for, it is already using SimpleXML.